# How can I ensure my system is ready for a full upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 16.10

My system keeps telling me that it can only form a partial upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10. I have a fairly standard Ubuntu installation. How can I have the system show me what the issues are, so that I can resolve them and perform a full upgrade?

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: There was no further detail offered... Grrr.

Answer (score 1):

This command should resolve the issue for the proposed partial upgrade.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Then go ahead and try the upgrade and see proposed updates for the system.

See what `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` has to say. After you run dist-upgrade say NO to upgrade, and see what the output says.

If its agreeable do that again this time answering yes.

Comment: I performed a "partial upgrade" eaerlier, and now running your suggested command says:

`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

I suppose that's that then. Thanks for then answer.

Comment: @Spider if that answered your question please mark as accepted :)

Comment: The answer was useful in that I learned something new, but no, it didn't answer my question. I eventually went with the partial upgrade option :)